# Intellij - disable vertical line/right margin

Tags: intellij-idea, margin

[image]

Just installed 2017.3 and it had returned...
Cannot find the setting to turn it off.

Comment: Got it :) It is called hard wrap now. Defaults to 120. Just set something higher.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IntelliJ IDEA 2017.3 version adds the ability to configure [multiple soft limits](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2017/11/intellij-idea-2017-3-new-preview-panel-for-svg-editor-multiple-soft-limits-and-more) for the file. This lets you configure several visual guides that will help control the width of the code. So the **Right margin** option (the characters lengts limit after which the code will be wrapped in Editor) was renamed to **Hard wrap at** option.